# How to parse multi-digit integers from string

Tags: java, parsing, int

I'm working on assignment here, part of which requires me to parse integers from a string that has groups of digits separated by any other character. I know I can use the wrapper class method Integer.parseInt(string) to parse ints from a string containing just digits, but how would I go about doing it in this case? So far, I've considered doing a linear search of the string and assigning a variable to the first index where a digit appears and the index after the last digit appears and creating a temporary substring based on these indices from which to parse the int. Is this a valid approach? Perhaps there is a more efficient one?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please show an example of the input you need to parse, that `Integer.parseInt()` _can't_ parse.

Comment: E.G. 23dfasf22323dfddfa223

should parse 23, 22323 and 223

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it can be any character (one or more), then this might be helpful:

```
String[] aarray = str.split("[^\\d]+");
```

E.g.:

```
String str = "12fdvvsd34.;h56s67.45c56";
String[] aarray = str.split("[^\\d]+");

for(int i = 0; i < aarray.length; i++)
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(aarray[i]));
```

Output:

```
12
34
56
67
45
56
```

Comment: Oh shit, that's exactly what I need. Didn't know string.split could take a regular expression as a parameter. Thanks a bunch!

EDIT: Almost what I need, I need an array of integers, not strings. Regardless, I think I can handle it from here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Let the API do the work, leading to this simple one-liner:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
```

Explanation:

- [`replaceAll("\\D", "")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) replaces all non-digits with blank, which effectively removes all non-digits, leaving you with just digit characters
- Pass the result (just digits) into [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can you java.util.String split method If you have a String with substrings separated by a token:

```
String data "123.345.55.66";
String [] fields = data.split(".");
```

If that's not what you want, you can slog through the details by looping over the String character by character:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
    char c = data.charAt(i);
    // manipulate as needed.
}
```

Comment: The second is essentially what I was thinking of doing.

 In theory though, if I were to use  string.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ".") and then used your suggestion for the split method, I'd be able to do it that way, right? Would this work if there were multiple non-digit characters in the digits? For example, if I tried to split 123.2223...33.3 to try and get 123, 2223, 33 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Integer findNumber(String s){
 List<String> num = Arrays.asList(s.split("[^0-9]"));
 for(String n : num) if(!n.isEmpty()) return Integer.parseInt(n);
}
```

The first line splits `s` around portions that match non-digit characters.

The second line then finds the first non-empty string of digits in the `List`.